# Unix: Find and rename multiple files with backslashes in filenames - Rename does not work

Tags: unix, replace, file-rename, backslash

I have a Nexenta NAS I'm running as an SMB fileserver.  So basically openindiana.  1 gigantic SMB share, shared with windows, OS X and linux clients. Somehow I ended up with a whole tree of files that have been named with their full windows path.  So for example:

"clientname - clientnameseriespreview\images\imagename.gif"   That whole thing is a filename, not a path.

This causes issues with both client access to those files, and backups, because both of those happen thru SMB, so although the \ char is fine as far as the Mac and Linux clients go, they can't see or touch them over SMB.

On the server itself I have tried every method I could find to rename them.  Properly escaped, find has no problem finding them but "rename" doesn't seem to be able to touch them at all.  Mv works fine, but I'm not sure how to script that to run against the whole tree(thousands of files).

Pretty much every reference I've found for this kind of renaming is along the lines of:

> find -name '*\\*' -type f | rename 's/\\/_/g'

Of which the find part works, but rename does nothing.  Not quite sure what I'm missing...

Thanks.

Comment: search here for `[bash] find mv print0` and you're certain to find several very good solutions. Good luck.

Comment: Hi shellter,  thanks for the response, I will do that and see what I can learn.  Appreciate the pointer, as I'd rather figure it out than just paste someone else's solution in...

Comment: @user3408072 You need to do `find . -name '*\\*' -type f | rename 's/\\/_/g'`.

Comment: Hi jaypal, That's actually exactly what I've been trying, the blockquote screwed up that line and I didn't realize it wasn't displaying correctly.  I'll try editing it so it's correct.

Comment: `rename` is not a standard command and there are different versions of it out there. (I didn't know any of them accepted filenames on stdin but apparently there's one that does.) Which one do you have?

Comment: Hi Wumpus,  it appears to be "rename from util-linux-2.12r".  Looks like the current ver of that package is 2.24 so my version is kinda ancient.  I'll look into updating it.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: The one you need for then `rename 's/.../.../'` syntax to work is perl rename.

Comment: How does one find the version of the perl rename?

Comment: After me spending way too much time on this, the owner of the files finally responded to me and it turns out they were just temp working files that had been dragged into that location by mistake and could be deleted.  So that's how I solved the problem.  Thanks to everyone who had suggestions, in spite of not figuring out how to do this particular task I learned a bunch of Bash stuff, so that's awesome.  Biggest problem, I think, is the oddball OS and it's tools being old/slightly different.